How to change the port of ng build with Angular 17
I have tried to use the deploy url with localhost:4100 but this did not change the port of the final builded server.mjs file in the dist folder
I would like to to have a different port than 4000 when i run the server.mjs file on a remote virtual machine

If you are talking about the listening port of the server side part of an Angular application that uses server side rendering, then this is not a build configuration, you have to configure it inside your server.ts file.
Inside your server.ts you should find a run function, you can either modify the port here, or if you havn't modified it, you could add an .env file with a PORT variable inside of it.
server.ts
function run(): void {
  // Here the listening port is defined.
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}


